# Components not visible then switch between panes in Java

Tags: java, components, hidden, panels

The problem is then I switch between panes, my buttons and text-fields become not visible, but then I drag cursor over components, they appear.
My Hierarchy looks similar to this:

JFrame

- PanelWithComponents
- _Button3
- PanelWithPanels
- _PanelOne
- __Button1
- __Label1(Background)
- _PanelTwo
- __Label2(Background)
- __Button2

  ```
  private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
   if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()){
      CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(bottomPanel.getLayout());
      cl.next(bottomPanel);

  }else{
      CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(bottomPanel.getLayout());
      cl.next(bottomPanel);


   }
  ```

  }

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the `revalidate()` and `repaint()` method when you switch the panes.

```
frame.getContentPane().revalidate();
frame.getContentPane().repaint();
```

From add method of `Container`.

`Note: If a component has been added to a container that has been displayed, validate must be called on that container to display the new component. If multiple components are being added, you can improve efficiency by calling validate only once, after all the components have been added.`

From remove method of `Container`.

`Note: If a component has been removed from a container that had been displayed, validate() must be called on that container to reflect changes. If multiple components are being removed, you can improve efficiency by calling validate() only once, after all the components have been removed.`

Edited as per camickr's comment.

Comment: I've tried to use it , but the frame gets underlined. I understand that it is JFrame, but I don't know how to get JFrame variable as an object. then I use the JFrame name, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add your code(atleast the portion where you make the switch between the panes).

Comment: I've tried to use it, but "frame" gets underlined. I understand that it is Jframe, but I can't get Jframe as an object.

Comment: can you just call `getContentPane().validate(); getContentPane().repaint();`?

Comment: @user3100454, when using Swing the code should be `revalidate(), repaint()`.